# Using list of vertex coordinates in csv file to create geometry, Sverchok addon

Tags: import, sverchok, csv

I am trying to import a csv file into blender, using the sverchok addon, and use one of the fields of the csv file to create geometry.

Here is my csv file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1YYlrie8CbP2eBErp90laizbZE9zvD9N2/view?usp=sharing

Blend file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vuHqgELdB9uGirzJZqjWDBiQbu8f9I4z/view?usp=sharing

The first field in this file, 'WKT' is the geometry data in [Well-Known Text](https://docs.opengeospatial.org/is/18-010r7/18-010r7.html) format. This geometry data is setup as such:

"MULTIPOLYGON (((286964.0223 5413712.8119,286957.0751 5413828.394,....)))" where:

- MULTIPOLYGON = description of the type of geometry
- 286964.0223 = x-coordinate of the first vertex
- 5413712.8119 = y-coordinate of the first vertex
- 286957.0751 = x-coordinate of the second vertex
- 5413828.394 = y-coordinate of the second vertex

Essentially, the 'WKT' field is a list of vertex coordinates. I would like to use these coordinates to create geometry, but am having trouble getting sverchok to recognize the 'WKT' as a list. To make this field recognizable as a list I've tried:

1. Removing the "MULTIPOLYGON " text
2. Changing the parentheses to brackets

These changes, along with different node trees using the string tools, numpy array, and various list nodes have not produced any results.

**How can I format/manipulate/process the 'WKT' field in my example file in order to create geometry through sverchok nodes?**

Thanks,

Comment: please provide blend file with what you tried so far.

Comment: thanks, I added a link to the blend file in the post